# Getting an error while reversing vowels in a string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector, data-structures

I know there are similar questions about this topic but I wanted to know error in my approach.

I'm writing a code to reverse vowels in a string. I first took all the vowels of a string into a vector and then I looped the string from backwards by replacing the vowels but I keep getting an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string reverseVowels(string s)
{
    vector<char>v;
    vector<char>v2;
    char c;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
                //taking all the vowels of the string into a vector
        if (s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'e' || s[i] == 'i' || s[i] == 'o' || s[i] == 'u')
        {
            v.push_back(s[i]);
        }
    }

        //reversing the vowels of the string
    for (int i = s.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'e' || s[i] == 'i' || s[i] == 'o' || s[i] == 'u')
        {
            s[i] = v[i];  //Getting an error here
        }
    }
    return s;
}

int main()
{
        //Required output is "holle"
    string s = "hello";
    string p = reverseVowels(s);
    cout << p << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if the size of string is 100? what is v[100]?

Comment: `v` shouldn't be indexed by `i` in this code... *ever*.

Comment: If you really want to do it this way then e.g. introduce new index for selecting a vowel from v vector. This is because the size of v will, in most cases, be lower than the size of s. And you try to get v[s.size() - 1].

Comment: Not a fix for your problem, but you do realise that you can do this reversal without using any extra storage?  There's no need for your vector of vowels at all.

Comment: This approach is rather heavy-handed. There's no need for that vector of vowels. Just scan from the front of the string until you hit a vowel, then scan from the back of the string until you hit a vowel, then exchange the two. Continue scanning from the points where you stopped. Repeat until the two scans meet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another index for the reversed vowels:

```
for (int vowelIdx = 0, i = s.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'e' || s[i] == 'i' || s[i] == 'o' || s[i] == 'u')
    {
        s[i] = v[vowelIdx++];  //Getting an error here
    }
}
```

**edit**

Regarding your comment below; let's examine the code for the word `hello`. The first loop runs through all the vowels in `hello` and fills the vector `v` as `eo`. It has two vowels with `e` as the first and `o` as the second/last element.

Your second loop reverse traverses the word `hello`, and encounters the first vowel `o`. You need to reset this to `e` which is the first element of the vector `v`. This is where your code get an error. The value of `i` is `4` now, hence you are trying to use the 4.th index of vector `v` which has only two elements. You have to set `s[4] = v[0]` and `s[1] = v[1]`. However, your code tries to set `s[4] = v[4]` (see the error?) and `s[1] = v[1]`.

Hope it's clear now, if not try it on paper with a longer word. I'm sure you will see the point.

Comment: Can you explain why do I need another index?

Comment: @philip see the edit.